# Ajax with jQuery alert me an xml file instead of the response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im using the below simple code to try out ajax with jquery.
The problem is that, whenever i keypress something inside the input. the script Alerts me something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="el-gr" lang="el-gr" dir="ltr" >
```

Am i missing anything important here ? as im completly noob both with ajax and jquery. For what im reading the syntax must be ok so im somewhere else wrong ?

THe 2 files im using:

**jQuery File**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#inputyo').keypress(function(){
        var query=$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"testajax.php",
            data:query,
            method:"GET",
            success: function(result){
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**testajax.php**

```
<?php 
echo "working!";
?>
```

Console log is empty and i have no errors or warnings at all.

Comment: are you testing your ajax on local server?

Comment: is this all you have in testajax.php? Maybe you have some html wrapped around it?

Comment: @jai No im testing it on a live site.

Comment: @n-dur i dont have anything else except that echo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe jquery fails because of a wrong interpretation of your servers headers

try to force a text detection

```
$.ajax({
    url:"testajax.php",
    data:query,
    dataType: 'text', 
    method:"GET",
    success: function(result){
        alert(result);
    }
});
```